# Ruby on Rails Logster gem: can the logs be displayed in a layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logster

I am using the logster gem: https://github.com/discourse/logster
and it is working properly, but I want the logs display to be inside my application layouts, and not on a separate page. (I want to display the logs along with my navigation sidebar, application header, footer, etc.)

Is there a way to have that with this gem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by using `iframe` to show the logs from logster.
Was not aware of that before